# HTML JS: Mi <script> no se ejecuta

Tags: javascript, html

Es dificil de explicar pero espero que se entienda: Estoy haciendo un juego de medicina, donde hay una tienda, y al comprar algo, hay una lista en la que se van añadiendo los items que compres.

Después, esta el inventario, y al abrirlo te muestra todos los elementos que tiene la lista de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al entrar al Inventario, un for recorre la lista y añade 2 lineas al HTML:

```
function checkInventory() {
if (user.inventario == "") {
    document.getElementById('onInventory').innerHTML = "<p style='margin-left: 30px;'>No tienes ningún objeto en tu inventario.</P>";
}else{
    for (let i = 0; i < user.inventario.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('onInventory').innerHTML += "<div class='inventorySlot' id=''>" + user.inventario[i] + "<br><input id='inventorySlot" + i + "' style='font-size: 50px;padding: 10px;' type='button' value='Abrir'</div>";
        document.body.innerHTML += 
        `<script>
        document.getElementById('inventorySlot${i}').addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert("hola");
            if (user.inventario[0] == "Muestra de Casa") {
                alert("Has abierto una Muestra de casa");
                user.inventario.splice(0, 1);
                updateUser();
            }else if (user.inventario[0] == "Muestra de Cloaca") {
                alert("Has abierto una Muestra de cloaca");
                user.inventario.splice(0, 1);
                updateUser();
            }
        });
        </script>
        `;
        console.log(i); 
    }
  }
}
```

AVISO: Uso localStorage, asique si quieren para hacerles mas facil probar el codigo, les dejo la clase `user`

```
class Usuario {
constructor(name, range, lvl, xp,  toLevelUp, money, enfermedades, inventario) {
    this.name = name; // Nombre
    this.range = range; // Rango
    this.lvl = lvl; // Nivel
    this.xp = xp; // Experiencia
    this.toLevelUp = toLevelUp; // Esto es la cantidad de xp que se necesita para subir de nivel
    this.money = money // Dinero
    this.enfermedades = enfermedades; // Enfermedades que conseguiste (LISTA)
    this.inventario = inventario; // Inventario (LISTA)
}

checkRange() {
    if (this.lvl == 0) {
        return "Invitado";
    }else if (this.lvl >= 1 && this.lvl <= 4) {
        return "Principiante";
    }else if (this.lvl >= 5 && this.lvl <= 9) {
        return "Standart";
    }else if (this.lvl >= 10 && this.lvl <= 14) {
        return "Experto";
    }else if (this.lvl >= 15 && this.lvl <= 19) {
        return "Experimentado";
    }else if (this.lvl >= 20 && this.lvl <= 29) {
        return "Doctor";
    }else if (this.lvl >= 30 && this.lvl <= 39) {
        return "Cirujano";
    }else if (this.lvl >= 40 && this.lvl <= 49) {
        return "Profesional";
    }
  }
}

user = new Usuario("Dr. Prueba", "Invitado", 0, 0, 50, 100, [], []);
```

> Retomando:

Por si no se entiende, la primera obviamente es el div que te muestra la caja del item, y el segundo, es un  que añade un .addEventListener() al boton de "Abrir", para que cuando presiones el boton se ejecute la secuncia de eliminar el item de la lista, guardar la clave en el localStorage y recargar la página.

Pero directamente no funciona, no pasa nada al apretar el boton y en consola no aparece información de un error ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Resolución

Al final, opte por usar otra alternativa, puse un maximo de 10 items y se generan .addEventListeners para cada uno de ellos (del 0-9)